# How to make CAS return to right Spring page

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

How do I change my XML file below to have CAS return to the right Spring back. If user goes to https://wcmisdlin07.uftmasterad.org:8443/MemberInquiry/requests/add.html and is not login  then it goes to the CAS server but returns to https://wcmisdlin07.uftmasterad.org:8443/MemberInquiry not https://wcmisdlin07.uftmasterad.org:8443/MemberInquiry/requests/add.html  how can I fix this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/cas-logout.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/casfailed.jsp" access="permitAll"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/requests/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER_INQUIRY')" />

        <custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/cas-logout.jsp"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="casAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <user-service id="userService">
        <user name="rod" password="rod" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_USER" />
        <user name="cpilling04@aol.com.dev" password="testing" authorities="ROLE_MEMBER_INQUIRY" />
    </user-service>

    <!-- This filter handles a Single Logout Request from the CAS Server -->
    <b:bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter"/>
    <!-- This filter redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
    <b:bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter"
        p:filterProcessesUrl="/j_spring_cas_security_logout">
        <b:constructor-arg value="https://${cas.server.host}/cas-server-webapp/logout"/>
        <b:constructor-arg>
            <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
        </b:constructor-arg>
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="serviceProperties"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties"
        p:service="https://${cas.service.host}/MemberInquiry/j_spring_cas_security_check"
        p:authenticateAllArtifacts="true"/>

    <b:bean id="casEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties" p:loginUrl="https://${cas.server.host}/cas-server-webapp/login" />

    <b:bean id="casFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="authManager"
        p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties"
        p:proxyGrantingTicketStorage-ref="pgtStorage"
        p:proxyReceptorUrl="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor">
        <b:property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
            <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
        </b:property>

        <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
                p:defaultFailureUrl="/casfailed.jsp"/>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>
    <!--
        NOTE: In a real application you should not use an in memory implementation. You will also want
              to ensure to clean up expired tickets by calling ProxyGrantingTicketStorage.cleanup()
     -->
    <b:bean id="pgtStorage" class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl"/>
    <b:bean id="casAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider"
        p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties"
        p:key="casAuthProviderKey">
        <b:property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
            <b:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <b:constructor-arg ref="userService" />
            </b:bean>
        </b:property>
        <b:property name="ticketValidator">
            <b:bean
                class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyTicketValidator"
                p:acceptAnyProxy="true"
                p:proxyCallbackUrl="https://${cas.service.host}/MemberInquiry/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor"
                p:proxyGrantingTicketStorage-ref="pgtStorage">
                <b:constructor-arg value="https://${cas.server.host}/cas-server-webapp" />
            </b:bean>
        </b:property>
        <b:property name="statelessTicketCache">
            <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.EhCacheBasedTicketCache">
                <b:property name="cache">
                    <b:bean class="net.sf.ehcache.Cache"
                      init-method="initialise"
                      destroy-method="dispose">
                        <b:constructor-arg value="casTickets"/>
                        <b:constructor-arg value="50"/>
                        <b:constructor-arg value="true"/>
                        <b:constructor-arg value="false"/>
                        <b:constructor-arg value="3600"/>
                        <b:constructor-arg value="900"/>
                    </b:bean>
                </b:property>
            </b:bean>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>

    <!-- Configuration for the environment can be overriden by system properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" properties-ref="environment"/>

    <util:properties id="environment">
        <b:prop key="cas.service.host">wcmisdlin07.uftmasterad.org:8443</b:prop>
        <b:prop key="cas.server.host">wcmisdlin07.uftmasterad.org:8443</b:prop>
    </util:properties>


</b:beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler to your casFilter which saves the request in the Request cache before authentication occurs and then redirects to the original destination. If no DefaultSavedRequest is found it redirects to the defaultTargetUrl which is the root of the application.

```
 <b:bean id="casFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authManager"
    p:serviceProperties-ref="serviceProperties"
    p:proxyGrantingTicketStorage-ref="pgtStorage"
    p:proxyReceptorUrl="/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor">
    <b:property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.authentication.ServiceAuthenticationDetailsSource"/>
    </b:property>

    <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            p:defaultFailureUrl="/casfailed.jsp"/>
    </b:property>

    <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
       <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            p:defaultTargetUrl="/"/>
   </b:property>

</b:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.
I have Java configuration for Spring Security and the following line solved my problem:
 savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirect");